# Having trouble with groupBy function

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble with the groupBy function I want to split at the number. Helpful if someone can point out  where I am going wrong

> Input "aba3dac4d"
>
> Desired Output ["aba", "3dac", "4d"]

But I get the output when I execute code

```
groupBy groupBy0' "aba3dac4d"
```

> ["aba", "3dac4d"]
>   Here is the code

```
import Data.List

groupBy0'::Char->Char->Bool
groupBy0' x y
  | x `elem` ['a'..'z'] && y `elem` ['0'..'9'] = False
  | x `elem` ['0'..'9'] && y `elem` ['a'..'z'] = True
  | x `elem` ['a'..'z'] && y `elem` ['a'..'z'] = True
  | x `elem` ['0'..'9'] && y `elem` ['0'..'9'] = True
  | otherwise = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy):

> ## The "By" operations
>
> By convention, overloaded functions have a non-overloaded counterpart
>   whose name is suffixed with `By`.
>
> It is often convenient to use these functions together with `on`, for
>   instance `` sortBy (compare `on` fst) ``.
>
> #### User-supplied equality (replacing an Eq context)
>
> The predicate is assumed to define an equivalence.

So, `groupBy pred` expects that `pred` is an equivalence relation, but yours is not, breaking the contract, so the result can not be relied upon. In particular, `groupBy groupBy0' "aba3dac4d"` is likely to perform these tests:

- `groupBy0' 'a' 'b'` is true, `'b'` in same group
- `groupBy0' 'a' 'a'` is true, `'a'` in same group
- `groupBy0' 'a' '3'` is false, `'3'` in *other* group
- `groupBy0' '3' 'd'` is true, `'d'` in same group
- `groupBy0' '3' 'a'` is true, `'a'` in same group
- `groupBy0' '3' 'c'` is true, `'c'` in same group
- `groupBy0' '3' '4'` is true, `'4'` in same group
- `groupBy0' '3' 'd'` is true, `'d'` in same group

As you can see, the above implementation of `groupBy`, we always compare with the first element in the group, not with the last one as you expect. Since `pred` is assumed to be an equivalence, it does not matter which element in the group we compare with. If we break this assumption, it matters.

You can't use `groupBy` to perform your particular function.

Answer (score 1):

As @chi clearly explains, you are not using `groupBy` correctly. In fact, I don't think `groupBy` is the correct function to use here. I would instead look at `takeWhile`.

Answer (score 1):

As @chi stated, you probably don't want `groupBy`; but here's something to get you started :)

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Data.List (span)
>>> span (not . isDigit) "ab2de4"
("ab","2de4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but you could achieve the same output with `chunksOf`

```
import Data.List.Split
chunksOf 3 "aba3ac4d"
```

Comment: Sorry I think I wasn't clear enough. What I want to do is split at the number.