# Strange behavior of groupBy

Tags: haskell

I am wondering why the following call of `groupBy` does not work: My predicate is `x < y`, so I expect `[1, 6]` to be a group, but instead, Haskell put `[1, 6, 4, 2]` into a group.

```
Prelude Data.List> groupBy (\x y -> x < y) [8,5,3,2,1,6,4,2]
[[8],[5],[3],[2],[1,6,4,2]]
```

More strangely, when I change the last number to -2, I expect the same behavior as in the above example. That is, since both 2 and -2 are less than 4, I expect that in the result `[1, 6, 4, -2]` would make up a group. But instead, This time, Haskell put -2 to be a group.

```
Prelude Data.List> groupBy (\x y -> x < y) [8,5,3,2,1,6,4,-2]
[[8],[5],[3],[2],[1,6,4],[-2]]
```

Do I have a wrong understanding of `groupBy`?

Comment: `groupBy` is intended to be used with an _equivalence relation_, specifically, in `groupBy p` you should have `p x y ≡ p y x`. But, I'm surprised that this is actually a _requirement_...

Comment: I mean, it's not a requirement. You can pass whatever function you want to `groupBy`. But you may get a surprising set of groups back if you use a surprising equality predicate.

Comment: @leftaroundabout @amalloy Thanks. I did not know `groupBy` "requires" an equality relation. Still, it would be interesting to know why -2 is handled differently than 2

Comment: `x` is always the *first* item of the group that is constructed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983130/having-trouble-with-groupby-function

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403293/need-to-partition-a-list-into-lists-based-on-breaks-in-ascending-order-of-elemen/14403413#14403413).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the implementation of the `groupBy`, `x` is always the *first* item of the sublist. Indeed, `groupBy` is implemented as:

> ```
> groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
> groupBy _  []           =  []
> groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
>                            where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
> ```

especially the `span (eq x)` is important here, since `x` will be the first item of a new group.

Since `x` is thus *not* the previous value in the list. If we thus run `groupBy` with the list `[5, 3, 2, 1, 6, 4, -2]`, we get:

| list | current list | x=? | check with | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[5,3,2,1,6,4,-2]` | `[8]` | `8` | `/` | `/` |
| `[5,3,2,1,6,4,-2]` | `[8]` | `8` | `5` | `False` |
| `[3,2,1,6,4,-2]` | `[5]` | `5` | `/` | `/` |
| `[3,2,1,6,4,-2]` | `[5]` | `5` | `3` | `False` |
| `[3,2,1,6,4,-2]` | `[3]` | `3` | `/` | `/` |
| `[2,1,6,4,-2]` | `[3]` | `3` | `2` | `False` |
| `[2,1,6,4,-2]` | `[2]` | `2` | `1` | `False` |
| `[1,6,4,-2]` | `[2]` | `2` | `/` | `/` |
| `[1,6,4,-2]` | `[2]` | `2` | `1` | `False` |
| `[6,4,-2]` | `[1]` | `1` | `/` | `/` |
| `[4,-2]` | `[1,6]` | `1` | `6` | `True` |
| `[-2]` | `[1,6,4]` | `1` | `4` | `True` |
| `[]` | `[-2]` | `-2` | `/` | `/` |

Especially the case where we compare `x=1` and `y=4` is important. If `x` was only the previous value, we should start generating a new list, but since `x` is the first item of the list, that is not the case.

Normally you should only work with an [*equivalence relation ~* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), such relation is:

1. *reflexive*: so `x ~ x` is true;
2. *symmetric*: so `x ~ y` if and only if `y ~ x`; and
3. *transitive*: so `x ~ y` and `y ~ z` implies that `x ~ z`.

Your equivalence relation is not reflexive, nor is it symmetric. This is thus *not* a valid function to work with `groupBy`.

Comment: this answer would be greatly upgraded, if you said what function the OP was thinking of, the one that compares neighbouring values to put group border or not

Answer (score 2):

The conceptual definition of `groupBy p l` is that it yields sublists of `l` such that for each `xs` in `l`, you have

```
all (==True) [p x y | x<-xs, y<-xs]
```

IOW, each sublist should be part of an *equivalence class* of `p`. That notion only makes sense if `p` is an *equivalence relation*. In particular, you need `p x y ≡ p y x`, and the defining equation also assumes that `p x x` is always true.

The implementation in the standard libraries shows that idea quite clearly: each `x:ys` list in the result has `ys` defined by the `span` of elements that are equivalent to `x` by the relation. So in your case, you get `1:[6,4,2]`, where `6,4,2` are all greater than `1`.

Evidently, `groupBy` doesn't actually check `p x y` for all pairs of elements in the result lists, so this really only makes sense if `p` is indeed an equivalence relation.

What you expected the idea to be – and IMO this is not unreasonable – is that only for all `x,y` such that `x` is the left neighbour of `y`, you want `p x y` to hold. This is in general a weaker condition, but if `p` is an equivalence relation then it actually implies the original condition, because such a relation also is *transitive*. So maybe the implementation should actually be

```
groupBy' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy' _ [] = []
groupBy' _ (x:l) = (x:xs) : zss
 where (xs,zss) = case l of
        [] -> ([],[])
        zs@(y:_)
         -> let ys:zss' = groupBy' p zs
            in if p x y then (ys, zss')
                        else ([], ys:zss')
```

(This could be simplified a bit, but then it wouldn't be as lazy as the old implementation.)